# Mysql is taking 63 GB from the server

Tags: php, mysql, performance, centos

I have a centos 6.9 in AWS which has mysql server Ver 5.6.36

I am facing really big slowness problem with exporting reports and most time it gives time out. the database side around 80G the server has 64G RAM and the mysql is using it all.
I am not a mysql specialist, so please if you need any statistic just ask me.
I do not know what I have to share.

but in the logs there is two errors. I do not know if these log related to the same problem.

```
2017-08-02 18:22:31 11629 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2017-08-02 18:22:31 11629 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

Comment: how big are the exported reports? how many tables are involved?

Answer (score 0):

We do need  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS  and  SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES  added to your question to quickly analyze key statistics and configuration information for your instance.  Thanks for offering the information.

The visual clues in the errors indicate second attempt to start another instance of MySQL.

TOP and MYTOP from your Centos server may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

- The error messages say that two copies of mysqld are running.  That is a no-no.
- Without the configuration, we cannot explain the "using it all".
- It is quite OK for a database to be bigger than RAM.  RAM is used to *cache* parts of the dataset.